# Array of pointers of base class; every program launch I have different results

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, memory

I have a task to create four classes - one base, two derived and a dynamic array that can store objects of derived ones. Base class should store name (some char string), and derived should have their unique voice() function. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

class Pet
{
public:
    char* name_;
    virtual void voice(){}
};

class Dog : virtual public Pet
{
public:
    Dog(char* str)
    {
        name_ = new char[strlen(str)];
        for(int i=0; str[i] != 0; ++i)
        {
            name_[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    virtual void voice()
    {
        std::cout<<"I'm a dog! My name is "<<this->name_<<std::endl;
    }
};

class Cat : virtual public Pet
{
public:
    Cat(char* str)
    {
        name_ = new char[strlen(str)];
        for(int i=0; str[i] != 0; ++i)
        {
            name_[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    virtual void voice()
    {
        std::cout<<"I'm a cat! My name is "<<this->name_<<std::endl;
    }
};

class Pack
{
private:
    Pet** pack_;
    int num;
public:
    Pack()
    {
        pack_ = new Pet*[0];
        num = 0;
    }
    void add(Pet* a)
    {
        Pet** newpack = new Pet*[num+1];
        for (int i = 0; i<num; ++i)
            newpack[i] = pack_[i];
        newpack[num] = a;
        ++num;
        for (int i = 0; i<num; ++i)
            pack_[i] = newpack[i];
        delete [] newpack;
    }
    void voiceall()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<num; ++i)
            pack_[i]->voice();
    }
};

int main() {
    Pack pack;
    for (int i=0; i<6; ++i)
    {
        char* str;
        std::cin.getline(str, 100);
        if (i%2 == 0)
        {
            Dog* a = new Dog(str);
            pack.add(a);
        }
        else
        {
            Cat* a = new Cat(str);
            pack.add(a);
        }
    }
    pack.voiceall();
    return 0;
}
```

This code seems to work, but, surprisingly for me, not every time I launch it. One third - one half of launches with the same input result in a error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS), usually in a `voiceall()` function of `Pack` class in a line `pack_[i]->voice();`. I'm too new in this whole base-derived-pointer thing and can't understand what's wrong.

**UPD:** Guys, I can't really use STL, because my teacher has very painful way of teaching things.

Comment: `pack_ = new Pet*[0];`

Comment: Every time different behavior is usually undefined behavior.

Comment: Then why does my program works SOMETIMES? It wouldn't be a problem if it crashes all the time.

Comment: Undefined Behavior  means anything can happen. Unfortunately for you it works some of the time.

Comment: Just `delete pack_`? Not `delete [] pack_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An immediate crash source is that you don't allocate any memory for your input – you're reading into an uninitialised pointer.

Replace

```
char* str;
```

with

```
char str[100];
```

Your name array is also one element too small; use

```
name_ = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
strcpy(name_, str);
```

Your `add` immediately deletes the array you need to store all the elements in.
You also write outside the bounds of your old array.

It should be more like this:

```
void add(Pet* a)
{
    Pet** newpack = new Pet*[num+1];
    // Copy the old array to the new.
    for (int i = 0; i<num; ++i)
        newpack[i] = pack_[i];
    // Add the new element to the new array.
    newpack[num] = a;
    ++num;
    delete [] pack_;  // Delete the old array...
    pack_ = newpack;  // ... and use the new one instead.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pack_ = new Pet*[0];
```

`pack` points to an array of size `0`.

```
++num;
```

You increment `num` to a number greater than `0`.

```
for (int i = 0; i<num; ++i)
        pack_[i] = newpack[i];
```

You access the array out of bounds. That results in undefined behaviour.

To fix it, don't access the array beyound it's bounds. You probably intended to allocate an array of size `num` and point `pack_` to that. Well, you do allocate an array, but you never update `pack_` so it's size never changes and you later delete the new, bigger array. I recommend using a `std::vector` to avoid bugs like this (as a bonus, it is also more efficient than what you're doing).

As a sidenote, you have many memory leaks. Avoid allocating dynamic memory manually and use `std::string` and `std::vector` to easily fix them.